# Why the copy of string does not take effect?

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, stl, pthreads

I'm doing some multi-thread programming.
It's a multi reader, single writer model.
I guess I use the pthread_rwlock in a proper way. When I assign to a string and sleep, the assign to the string always results empty.
Could someone told me what's wrong with my code? THX.

## See the FIXME comment in the code.

```
#include "util/tc_thread.h"
#include "util/tc_thread_rwlock.h"

using namespace taf;

static string g_buffer;
static pthread_rwlock_t g_lock;

class TestThread: public TC_Thread
{
    public:
        TestThread(int type, const string &_msg): m_type(type), m_msg(_msg)
    {
        if (type == 2)
        {
            printf("writer get m_msg: %s\n", m_msg.c_str());
        }
    }
        ~TestThread()
        {
            //printf("Destroy thread of type %d\n", m_type);
        }
    protected:
        void run()
        {
            if (m_type == 1)
            {
                //Reader
                pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&g_lock);
                printf("%s\n", g_buffer.c_str());
                usleep(2000000); //FIXME::If I drop this line or move it below pthread_rwlock_unlock, the two ways of assign to g_buffer both take effects.
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&g_lock);

            }
            else if (m_type == 2)
            {
                //Writer
                pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&g_lock);
                printf("==succ: %s\n", g_buffer.c_str());
                printf("==succ: %s\n", m_msg.c_str());
                g_buffer = m_msg; //FIXME::Here, the g_buffer will be empty
                //g_buffer = m_msg.data(); //FIXME:: If I assign g_buffer like this, the result is right.
                printf("==succ: %s\n", g_buffer.c_str());
                printf("==succ: %s\n", m_msg.c_str());
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&g_lock);
            }
            else if (m_type == 3)
            {
                while (1)
                {
                    printf("type 3 thread is working\n");
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
            pthread_exit((void *)(0));
        }
    private:
        int m_type;
        string m_msg;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_rwlockattr_t attr;
    pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np(&attr, PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NONRECURSIVE_NP);
    pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_rwlock_init(&g_lock, &attr);

    TestThread trd(3, "Hello1");
    trd.start();

    TestThread fst(2, "Hello1");
    fst.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        TestThread t(1, "Hello 9");
        t.start();
    }
    TestThread snd(2, "Hello2");
    snd.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        TestThread t(1, "Hello 10");
        t.start();
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)(0));
}
```

=================================================

When the writer thread snd tries to set g_buffer to "Hello2", the g_buffer turns to be empty. The TC_Thread is a private library which I don't have code. But it is thoroughly tested, so it's not possible to be the cause of this problem.

Comment: There is no way to test your code without access to the private library. Please take time to rewrite your example so that the problem is reproducible by others.